# Magento 2 error - Model/View/Page/Config/RendererFactory.php on line 64

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, cache, composer

I have a very annoying error on my production site which occurs once a day. My site goes down with the error below and I have to refresh cache to resolve the problem. It's Magento 2.1.7 with multistore setup. Has anyone had this issue?

There has been an error processing your request

> Notice: Undefined index:  in /public_html/vendor/magento/module-developer/Model/View/Page/Config/RendererFactory.php on line 64

Log File:

> a:4:{i:0;s:141:"Notice: Undefined index:  in
>   /home/bargaink/public_html/vendor/magento/module-developer/Model/View/Page/Config/RendererFactory.php
>   on line 64";i:1;s:10136:"#0
>   /home/bargaink/public_html/vendor/magento/module-developer/Model/View/Page/Config/RendererFactory.php(64):
>   Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(8, 'Undefined index...',
>   '/home/bargaink/...', 64, Array)

```
#1 /home/bargaink/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(149): Magento\Developer\Model\View\Page\Config\RendererFactory->create(Array)
#2 /home/bargaink/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(139): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->initPageConfigReader()
#3 /home/bargaink/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(14): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\ReaderPool), Object(Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\BuilderFactory), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool), Object(Magento\Developer\Model\View\Page\Config\RendererFactory), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Page\Layout\Reader), 'Magento_Theme::...', false)
#4 /home/bargaink/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(93): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\ReaderPool), Object(Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\BuilderFactory), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool), Object(Magento\Developer\Model\View\Page\Config\RendererFactory), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Page\Layout\Reader), 'Magento_Theme::...', false)
#5 /home/bargaink/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(88): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#6 /home/bargaink/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(57): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#7 /home/bargaink/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/PageFactory.php(55): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#8 /home/bargaink/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/View.php(74): Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory->create(true)
#9 /home/bargaink/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(93): Magento\Framework\App\View->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Framework\Config\Scope), Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory), Object(Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag))
#10 /home/bargaink/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(88): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#11 /home/bargaink/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(130): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\\Framewo...')
#12 /home/bargaink/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(67): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->get('Magento\\Framewo...')
#13 /home/bargaink/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(130): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\\Framewo...')
#14 /home/bargaink/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(67): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->get('Magento\\Framewo...')
#15 /home/bargaink/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(57): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#16 /home/bargaink/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ActionFactory.php(40): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Framewo...')
#17 /home/bargaink/public_html/vendor/magento/module-url-rewrite/Controller/Router.php(90): Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory->create('Magento\\Framewo...')
#18 /home/bargaink/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(50): Magento\UrlRewrite\Controller\Router->match(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#19 /home/bargaink/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#20 /home/bargaink/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#21 /home/bargaink/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'requestPreproce...')
#22 /home/bargaink/public_html/vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#23 /home/bargaink/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#24 /home/bargaink/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#25 /home/bargaink/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#26 /home/bargaink/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 /home/bargaink/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'searchautocompl...')
#28 /home/bargaink/public_html/app/code/Mirasvit/SearchAutocomplete/Model/App/FrontController/Plugin.php(130): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#29 /home/bargaink/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Mirasvit\SearchAutocomplete\Model\App\FrontController\Plugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#30 /home/bargaink/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#31 /home/bargaink/public_html/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/VarnishPlugin.php(55): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#32 /home/bargaink/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\VarnishPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#33 /home/bargaink/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#34 /home/bargaink/public_html/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(68): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#35 /home/bargaink/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#36 /home/bargaink/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'Amasty_GeoipRed...')
#37 /home/bargaink/public_html/app/code/Amasty/GeoipRedirect/Plugin/Action.php(147): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#38 /home/bargaink/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Amasty\GeoipRedirect\Plugin\Action->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#39 /home/bargaink/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#40 /home/bargaink/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#41 /home/bargaink/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#42 /home/bargaink/public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#43 {main}";s:3:"url";s:29:"/the-sims-4-get-together.html";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}
```

Thanks

Comment: rename vendor and install again composer. it may help you

Comment: Hi Pramod, can you provide some more detail on how to do this? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Go to **Admin panel** -> **Stores** -> Settings -> **Configuration** -> **Advanced** -> **Developer**

Then from the dropdown called "**Frontend Development Workflow**" -> Select the option called "**Server side less compilation**" -> **Save Config**.

This should fix the problem if your system is using the "**Client side less compilation**", which is *not allowed in production mode*.